# Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecoratorsگ

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I am new in angular
I create a project for training, I created a project which worked fine but after adding this component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'submit-form',
  templateUrl: './SubmitForm.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./SubmitForm.component.css']
})
export class SubmitFormComponent {
  profileForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    lastName: [''],
    address: this.fb.group({
      street: [''],
      city: [''],
      state: [''],
      zip: ['']
    }),
    aliases: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.control('')
    ])
  });

  get aliases() {
    return this.profileForm.get('aliases') as FormArray;
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  updateProfile() {
    this.profileForm.patchValue({
      firstName: 'Nancy',
      address: {
        street: '123 Drew Street'
      }
    });
  }

  addAlias() {
    this.aliases.push(this.fb.control(''));
  }

  onSubmit() {
    // TODO: Use EventEmitter with form value
    console.warn(this.profileForm.value);
  }
}
```

I got this error :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS1219  Build:Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.
```

I checked the tsconfig and this option

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
```

I gots a lot of errors

[image]

Comment: What versions of angular and typescript are you using and are installed?  (that can be conflicting)

Comment: @GeoDev would you please let me know how can I do that ?

Comment: Check your `package.json` for your version you are aiming for

Comment: And check it against node `node -v` and your installed packages (often global) `npm list -g`

Comment: @GeoDev    thank you . "@angular/core": "^14.1.3",   "typescript": "~4.7.4"

Comment: And what does  `node -v` say when you type it in command line

Comment: @GeoDev v14.21.3